# Dart async/await pattern explanation

Tags: dart, async-await, dart-async

I am trying to use the async/await pattern in my app because I don't like carrying `Future`'s everywhere.

What I want to achieve is given this method:

```dart
Future<Map> loadConfig() {
  return Config.loadConfig().then((config) {
    // do some assertions in here
  });
}
```

and the caller:

```dart
void main() {
  Future<Map> config = loadConfig()
  .then((config) {
    // do complicated stuff, and have other async calls.    
    app.run(config);
  });
}
```

Is there a way I can use the async/await feature to make the code more pretty? I tried something like this:

```dart
Map loadConfig async () {
  Map config = await Config.loadConfig();
  // do some assertions on config
  return config;
}
```

and the caller:

```dart
void main() async {
  Map config = await loadConfig();
  // do complicated stuff, and have other async calls.    
  app.run(config);
}
```

and what it tells me in the `loadConfig` method is that `type '_Future' is not a subtype of type 'Map' of 'function result'.` as if the result of the `await something()` returns a `Future<typeOfSomething>`... isn't the point of all this to somewhat get rid the the `Future` and make it look like it's sync code?

As a side note, I am using

```dart
 ❯ dartanalyzer --version
dartanalyzer version 1.8.3
```

And for some reason it's not recognizing `async` and `await` keywords/syntax. Is there a switch to tell it to use the async features?

**edit**: maybe I'm doing something wrong but here's what I have tested after @Günter Zöchbauer's answer.

loadConfig() function:

```dart
Future<Map> loadConfig() {
  return Config.loadConfig().then((config) {
    assert(config["listeningPort"] != null);
    assert(config["gitWorkingDir"] != null);
    assert(config["clientPath"] != null);
    assert(config["websitePath"] != null);
    assert(config["serverPath"] != null);
    assert(config["serverFileName"] != null);
    assert(config["gitTarget"] != null);
    assert(config["clientHostname"] != null);
    print("Loaded config successfully");
  });
}
```

And my main caller function:

```dart
Map config = await loadConfig();
if (config == null) {
  print("config is null");
}
var patate = loadConfig().then((otherConfig) {
  if (otherConfig == null) {
    print("other config is null");
  }
});
```

which prints

```dart
Loaded config successfully
config is null
Loaded config successfully
other config is null
```

Any idea why?

**edit2:**

As pointed out by Gunter and Florian Loitsch, I had to write the `loadConfig` function like this:

```dart
Future<Map> loadConfig() {
  return Config.loadConfig().then((config) {
    assert(config["listeningPort"] != null);
    assert(config["gitWorkingDir"] != null);
    assert(config["clientPath"] != null);
    assert(config["websitePath"] != null);
    assert(config["serverPath"] != null);
    assert(config["serverFileName"] != null);
    assert(config["gitTarget"] != null);
    assert(config["clientHostname"] != null);
    print("Loaded config successfully");
    return config;
  });
}
```

Comment: async only changes the body of a function. You are still returning a Map. You need the `Future` return value of loadConfig: `Future<Map> loadConfig() async {`.

Comment: The updated version prints `null` because your `then` functions don't return anything. You would need to `return config` in the last line after the `print("Loaded config successfully")`. Think of `.then` as a `.map` on Futures (like the `.map` on a `List`).

Comment: I don't know  why, but we had a big discussion mentioning that under Gunter's answer, and it's now gone. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the `loadConfig` function. The changes you applied to `main()` should do.